# SQL- getting a count from Table (LEFT JOIN) with criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have the following tree tables and I want to achieve the Table named "wanted result".
On the first are the house names, on the second the name of the rooms of each house and on the third the price of each room.
I want a count of rooms by house.

table_1

```
nid    name
1      House 1
2      House 2 
3      House 3
```

table_2

```
Name     house_ref_id    id
Room1    1               20
Room1    2               21
Room1    2               22
Room1    3               23
Room1    3               24
```

table_3

```
Price    room_ref_id
0        20
100      21
150      22
0        23
120      24
```

Wanted result:

```
nid      name       Rooms w/ price
1        House1     0
2        House2     2
3        House3     1
```

I have tried the following code but could get the right  amount of rooms with price

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(price) AS "rooms w/ price" FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.ref_id
LEFT JOIN table_3 ON table_2.room_ref_id = table_3.id 
WHERE table_3.price>0
GROUP BY table_1.nid
```

but got the following:

```
nid     name      rooms w/ price
1       nouse1    1
2       house2    2
3       house3    2
```

Comment: `WHERE table_3.price=0  OR table_3.price IS NULL  ` ?

Comment: According to your data, `nid = 1` should not be in the output at all.  You should also fix the tags to match the database you are really using.

Comment: Thank you gordon, I forgot to include the nid on the SELECT clause, but I fixed it now, thanks for the answer

Comment: mysql <> sql server

Comment: @scsimon, thank you I have removed the tag to avoid future confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close.  The condition in the `WHERE` turns the outer joins into inner joins.  You need to move it to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(table3.id) AS "rooms w/ price"
FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN
     table_2 
     ON table_1.id = table_2.ref_id LEFT JOIN
     table_3
     ON table_2.room_ref_id = table_3.id AND table_3.price > 0
GROUP BY table_1.nid;
```

Comment: Thank you, That really worked!
I will look again better on the Where Clause works.
Many thanks